# Form submissions and PHP best practice

Tags: php, forms, function, codeigniter

In Codeigniter and other PHP applications, what's generally considered the more efficient practice:

1.) Submitting a form to the same function using a hidden 'submitted' input:

```
public function standard_form()
{
   if($this->input->post('submitted'))
   {
      // Process data
   }
   else
   {
      // Render form view
   }
}
```

2.) Submitting a form to a different function as follows:

```
public function standard_form()
{
    // Render form view
}

public function standard_form_process()
{
    // Process data
}
```

I know some people will frown upon the 'subjective' nature of this question, but I want to know any strategic (i.e. relatively *objective*) benefits of using one instead of the other.

Comment: @Jaime: Just an FYI, since it appears you're working with CodeIgniter, you can take advantage of the `Form Validation` class and the its `run()` method so you don't need to embed any hidden <input> elements. [You can read more here](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html).

Comment: @Colin thanks for that. I always used the form validation in a separate function, but I never realised that the run() method kills two birds with one stone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the same one so if it fails validation, and you reload the page, it's the same URL, same bookmark, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I always use **1.)** version unless my code is really complex and is better to use **2.)** for a better manipulation of the data and the output of it.